# Erb with Sinatra in ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

So I have a webserver I've built using sinatra, the meat of which goes like this:

```
set :variable,"value"
get '/' do
  erb :index
end
```

And, of course, the template in `views/index.erb` which looks something like this:

```
<html>
<!-- etc -->
  <ul>
  <% my_array.each do |thing| %>
  <%="Something: #{thing}, variable from sinatra: #{settings.variable}"%>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</html>
```

If you try running code like this you'll notice that you can't access sinatra's settings variable from inside erb templates. Any ideas how I can achieve this while keeping its simplicity?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I asked this question for haml, maybe the answer will help you in erb:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129387/how-do-i-get-an-array-of-check-boxes-in-haml

Comment: I'm guessing those settings are available in the controller? If you want them available in the view you'd have to pass them.

Comment: My answer was wrong. The settings method should be available from the view. The code you posted works fine for me.

Comment: Odd, I'll have to do more testing! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using an old version of Sinatra - updated to version 1.0 and it works fine :)

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the resolution was to make sure all the `set :x, "y"` stuff happened in the class declaration (of my subclass of `Sinatra::Base`) outside of the initialize method.